# Backup and disaster management plans for mysql database

Tags: mysql, backup, disaster-recovery

I've got a multi-user application having some critical data of the users. I am working on the backup and disaster recovery plan for the application..

Would like to know some best practices regarding this..

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: you may want to include failover in your critical data management.

Backup is often used for copy of your data ready to be restored.

[Failover and DRP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120139/failover-disaster-recovery) restore the ***service*** (not just the data), since a new server is available:

- within few minutes for failover, since it is generally on the same nettwork, and its name does not have to be published on the various DNS
- within a few hours in case of DRP

For pure backup strategy, I go with daily incremental backup, and weekly full backup.

However, we also have a [SRDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRDF) connection allowing a real-time data replication with our remote data center used for DRP.

Now, backup + failover + SRDF (for DRP) might be overkill for development data, but can be justified for **production** data (needed to restore the service running in production).

So to better refine your policies, you need to clearly analyze what your data represent.